# prettyCheckable on jqGrid doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, css, checkbox, jqgrid

I have a *jqGrid* table (that converts a table to grid) with multi-select checkboxes.
To customize the checkbox style I used **[prettyCheckable](http://arthurgouveia.com/prettyCheckable/)**, that generates a label and an anchor (href) and div container for checkbox input (that is hidden and covered by label  and a). My issue is that when i check the label doesn't work, instead when i check the input works.


[image: Label checked]

[image: Input checked]

```
<div class="clearfix prettycheckbox labelright  blue " id="aui_11140">
    <input role="checkbox" id="rs" class="cbx" type="checkbox" style="display: none;">
    <label for="rs" class="checked" id="aui_11139">
    </label>
</div>
```

setting prettyCheckable for inputs :

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
        $(this).triggerHandler("click");
    }).prettyCheckable();
```

And this is my jqGrid settings:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#searchForm').ajaxForm(function() {
        var _data = $('#searchForm').serialize();
        $('#ResultsTable').jqGrid().setGridParam({url: '${searchUrl}' + _data}).trigger("reloadGrid")
        return true;
    });
    jsonTable('ResultsTable', 'ResultsPager', '${searchUrl}', 'searchForm',
        {id: 'code'},
        ['Code', 'Description', 'CF'],
        [{name: 'code', index: 'code', width: 55},
        {name: 'description', index: 'description', width: 90},
        {name: 'CF', index: 'CF', width: 80},
        function(id) {
            var selRows = $(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');
            $('#edit').toggle(selRows.length == 1);
            $('#delete').toggle(selRows.length > 0);
            $('#editForm #code').val(selRows);
            $('#deleteForm #code').val(selRows);
        },
        function(aSel, selected) {
            $('#edit').toggle(false);
            $('#delete').toggle(selected);
            if (selected) {
                $('#editForm #code').val(selRows);
                $('#deleteForm #code').val(selRows);
            }
        },
        true
    )      
});
```

Why this doesn't work?

ps. i have edited the *prettyCheckable.js* and removed the `<a>` therefore is not generated. And i renamed the css from `.prettycheckbox a {}` to `.prettycheckbox label {}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin `prettyCheckable` uses code like

```js
input.prop('checked', true).change();
```

to forward the changes of the state to the checkbox. On the other side jqGrid contains `click` event handle only (see [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.5.2/js/grid.base.js#L2465)).

What you can do is triggering of `click` event in case of `change` event.

For example, let us you have grid with `id="list"`. Then the `id` of the checkbox to select all items will be `cb_list` ("cb_" appended with the grid id). So you use probably the code like

```js
$("#cb_list").prettyCheckable();
```

I suggest that you change the code to the following

```js
$("#cb_list").change(function() {
    $(this).triggerHandler("click");
}).prettyCheckable();
```

It should fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much! now it works fine! but there is another problem that I have not explained. Checkbox style changes only for the first input.

Comment: @Fuiba: You are welcome! Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean under "the first input" and which checkbox style you mean. Could you describe your problem more clear? You don't included the code which you use for `prettyCheckable`. Which chechboxs you change? Your screenshort contains only the chechbox in the column header of the multiselect column. Do you have problem with the checkbox or with another one?

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't explain well. In the above image you can see the classic checkbox and the customized checkbox. From Firebug I removed the `display:none` style to the input and i makeed the screenshot to show it to you (to see the input and the label). This is the screenshot without changes from Firebug http://imageshack.us/a/img600/2686/s8v.jpg. Why the first checkbox has the image style and all other checkboxes has default style even though I used a general class for all checkboxes? (I edited my question by adding the jQuery code)

Comment: @Fuiba: Do you mean that you need use `prettyCheckable` for **every** chechbox of the multiselect column? I don't know *which code you use to do this*, but I am afraid you will have other problems. If you use `loadComplete: function () {$(this).find("input.cbox").prettyCheckable();}` then you would have all chechboxes, but you have to write additional code to make all working in jqGrid.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works but the selectAll doesn't work: http://imageshack.us/a/img208/6420/7fxn.jpg when i check the first checkbox to select all doesn't select all, and when i uncheck it this select all (as you can see in the image). I appreciate the time and effort you have spent sorting out this problem. Thank you.

Comment: @Fuiba: I wrote you before that usage of `prettyCheckable` for **all**  checkboxes will require that you write many additional code. You have to implement `onSelectAll` and `onSelectRow` which make selection of the checkboxes. `prettyCheckable.js` bind `click` on `a` and `label` but if jqGrid set the state of checkbox (which made hidden by ) **not** control changing of stat hidden checkbox. I wrote you that you could need write many code to full implement `prettyCheckable` in jqGrid.

Comment: @Fuiba: For example `onSelectRow: function (rowid) { $("#jqg_" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.id + "_" + rowid)).next("a").toggleClass('checked'); }` could be required or probably more complex code. In the same way you will need implement `onSelectAll` which add or remove `checked` class from `<a>` parts of prettyCheckable.

Comment: I posted the code of my jqGrid settings and i tried with `onSelectRow: function (rowid) { $("#jqg_" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.id + "_" + rowid)).next("a").toggleClass('checked'); }` but doesn't work.

Comment: @Fuiba: I'm wonder **why** you use so strange values for ids. You use `$('#<portlet:namespace/>edit')` and  `document.getElementById('<portlet:namespace/>edited')`. It means that you have really id="<portlet:namespace/>edited"? Is it so? I think that such names are incorrect as `id` in HTML. Why you use so really crazy ids? By the way the expression `$('#<portlet:namespace/>edit')` will be wrong if the `id="<portlet:namespace/>edited"`.

Comment: Because this table code is written to be displayed on Liferay (java), and ids are generated later. I just want to understand how to use prettyCheckable under jqGrid without getting any issue.

Comment: @Fuiba: You should understand that selector `#test>a` means collection of all `<a>` elements which are direct children of elements with `id="test"`. If you use `$('#<portlet:namespace/>edit')` then jqGrid will search `<edit>` elements which are direct children of element with `id=<portlet:namespace/`. To tell the trust I am not sure that the id selector `$('#<portlet:namespace/')` has correct syntax. One have to **escape** special characters or better **don't use exotic ids**. See [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier).

Comment: @Fuiba: some parts of the code could not work (or wrong work) because it don't support such exotic id values. See [here]([here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)) examples of escaping selectors used with jQuery.

Comment: Thank you very much for giving me a tip, I have changed the ids and i updated my code above. Now i'll try with `onSelectRow: function (rowid) { $("#jqg_" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.id + "_" + rowid)).next("a").toggleClass('checked'); }`

Comment: @Fuiba: Could you show **where** you use `$("input[type=checkbox]").change` in your code?

Comment: @Fuiba: It's better if you opens new question where you post the code and describe the problem. If we write the information in comments it would be **not indexed** and other user would not find the information during searching on the stackoverflow.

Comment: I used this: `$("input.cbox").change(function() {
  $(this).triggerHandler("click");
 }).prettyCheckable();`

Comment: @Fuiba: My question is **where in your code**? The problem is that `$("input.cbox").change(...);` set handler on **current existing** checkboxes, but not on checkboxes created later.

Comment: I have opened a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17186822/prettycheckable-on-jqgrid-multiselect
 Thank you very much Oleg!