# prettyCheckable on jqGrid Multiselect

Tags: jquery, checkbox, jqgrid

I have a *jqGrid* table with multi-select checkboxes that I have customized with CSS and [**prettyCheckable**](http://arthurgouveia.com/prettyCheckable/).

To customize all the checkboxes of my table I set `.prettyCheckable()` as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
        $(this).triggerHandler("click");
    }).prettyCheckable();
});
```

but this doesn't work. Only the first checkbox has the style.

[image: jqGrid]

So i tried to insert the function `.prettyCheckable()` into `loadComplete` of *jqGrid*, and as suggested by *Oleg* [#here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144547/prettycheckable-on-jqgrid-doesnt-work#comment24825482_17145310), by adding checked class for `<a>`.

This is my jqGrid settings:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#searchForm').ajaxForm(function() {
        var _data = $('#searchForm').serialize();
        $('#ResultsTable').jqGrid().setGridParam({
            url: '${searchUrl}' + _data,
            loadComplete: function () {
                $(this).find("input.cbox").prettyCheckable();
            }
        }).trigger("reloadGrid")
        return true;
    });
    jsonTable('ResultsTable', 'ResultsPager', '${searchUrl}', 'searchForm',
        {id: 'code'},
        ['Code', 'Description', 'CF'],
        [{name: 'code', index: 'code', width: 55},
        {name: 'description', index: 'description', width: 90},
        {name: 'CF', index: 'CF', width: 80},
        function(id) {
            var selRows = $(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');
            $('#edit').toggle(selRows.length == 1);
            $('#delete').toggle(selRows.length > 0);
            $('#editForm #code').val(selRows);
            $('#deleteForm #code').val(selRows);
            //$("#jqg_" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.id + "_" + id)).next("a").toggleClass('checked');
        },
        function(aSel, selected) {
            $('#edit').toggle(false);
            $('#delete').toggle(selected);
            if (selected) {
                $('#editForm #code').val(selRows);
                $('#deleteForm #code').val(selRows);
            }
        },
        true
    )      
});
```

but also with this does not work, how can I solve this problem?

I have created a small demo here: jsfiddle.net/LStvX/1 
Any help is appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: What is the function `jsonTable`? The function seems to do the main work. Could you include the code of the function too?

Comment: It's not important how you exactly use `prettyCheckable` in your code. The goal of stackoverflow is sharing *common* problem and it's solution with other. Your current code contains `$('#searchForm').ajaxForm(..)` for example. Is it related to your main problem? Is it not better to create *small demo which just demonstrate your main problem*? After the problem will be solved in the demo you can transform the solution to your main code.

Comment: I have created a small demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/LStvX/1/

Comment: This is my `jsonTable` function: http://pastebin.com/xguJiJDt

Comment: You chosen jQuery in old version 1.6.4. I see some errors which will be away if one use at least 1.7.2 version. Do you really use jQuery 1.6.4 in your project? Is it really required?

Comment: I'm sorry I made a mistake. I use the last version 1.10. I updated the fiddle.

Comment: Another question: who is the owner of `prettyCheckable`? You used it from [here](http://bestware.us/prettyCheckable/prettyCheckable.js) and I found [here](http://arthurgouveia.com/prettyCheckable/js/prettyCheckable/prettyCheckable.js) before the versions which code is **different from the code which you use**. It's unclear for me which version is the last one? [The source](http://arthurgouveia.com/prettyCheckable/) seems to me the official origin.

Comment: @Oleg I have added the official version ([see here] (jsfiddle.net/LStvX/14)) but this does not solve the problem. When i select all works fine but I do not see the ticks for selected.

Comment: It's clear. I don't wrote that usage another version of `prettyCheckable` would solve your problem. I never used `prettyCheckable` before and I wanted just know which version of it should be used. I'll look at the problem later and then I'll post my answer with suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I find integration of other plugins in jqGrid interesting. I didn't used [prettyCheckable](http://arthurgouveia.com/prettyCheckable/) before. After same analyse of the way how `prettyCheckable` works I created [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/prettyCheckable.htm) which demonstrate an example of such integration. The results look like on the picture below

[image]

To understand the code one should understand that `prettyCheckable` convert original HTML fragment of the cell with multiselect checkbox

[image]

in more complex structure

[image]

I find not good that `prettyCheckable` always create empty `<label>` element which increase the height of the column. So I added the code which make all the `<label>` element hidden.

The next problem is that `prettyCheckable` uses `<a>` element with optional class `"checked"` for chechboxes and inform the original checkbox (which are hidden after initialization `prettyCheckable`) per `change` event, but jqGrid wait for `click` event on the row or on the checkbox and have no reaction on `change` event.

I skip some less interesting technical details now. The most important parts of the code of the demo you find below

```js
$("#list").jqGrid({
    ...
    multiselect: true,
    multiselectWidth: 28,
    onSelectAll: function (aRowids, status) {
        var i, l = aRowids.length, $a,
            selector = "#jqg_" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.id) + "_";

        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            $a = $(selector + $.jgrid.jqID(aRowids[i])).next("a");
            if (status) {
                $a.addClass("checked");
            } else {
                $a.removeClass("checked");
            }
        }
    },
    beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
        if (e.target.nodeName.toUpperCase() === "A" &&
                $(e.target).prev("input").hasClass("cbox")) {
            $(e.target).prev("input").click();
        }
        return true;
    },
    onSelectRow: function (rowid, state) {
        var $a = $("#jqg_" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.id + "_" + rowid)).next("a");
        if (state) {
            $a.addClass("checked");
        } else {
            $a.removeClass("checked");
        }
    },
    loadComplete: function () {
        var $checkboxes = $(this).find("input.cbox");
        $checkboxes.prettyCheckable();
        $checkboxes.siblings("label").hide();
    }
});
$("#cb_" + $.jgrid.jqID($grid[0].id)).change(function() {
    $(this).triggerHandler("click");
}).prettyCheckable();
$("#cb_" + $.jgrid.jqID($grid[0].id)).siblings("label").hide();
```

I used additional CSS settings (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7256972/315935)) to increase the height of the column headers

```css
th.ui-th-column div {
    white-space: normal !important;
    height: auto !important;
}
```