# Add Class to CheckBox when multiSelect true

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am having a `Delete` option in my Grid and I am using the `MultiSelect` option set to `true`. To fancy my checkbox I am planning to use `imaged checkboxes` instead of standard ones.

I am done with putting the imaged checkboxes in a standard div.

Now I am trying the same option for `JqGrid` checkboxes with `MultiSelect` set to `true`.

What I need to do is 'add a Class to the checkbox' when the `multiSelect` option is set.

How do I add classes to `JqGrid` checkboxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple adding of a class to the checkbox is not enough in the most cases. Probably want you want is very close to another previously answered question. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/prettyCheckable.htm) created for [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17186822/315935). You can see that the code includes `onSelectAll`, `beforeSelectRow`, `onSelectRow` and `loadComplete` callbacks. You should take in the consideration that the code of jqGrid uses *standard checkboxes* which it creates in case of usage of `multiselect: true`. All modification which you do should not break existing jqGrid code.

Comment: Agree @Oleg. What is the easiest way to add a class ? as am not using much events in JqGrid. Thanks for your quick Answer +1

Comment: @Peru: You are welcome! Where exactly you want to add the class? You can cor example use *existing* `cbox` class of checkboxes. Alternatively you can add your own class to chechboxes inside of `loadComplete`. For example `loadComplete: function () { $(this).find("input.cbox").addClass("myClass"); }`

Comment: Thanks @Oleg tat sample answers mine :) but is it possible to load before the load completes when the checkboxes are created

Comment: @Peru: You wrote: "is it possible to load ..." What you want to load? The chechboxes will be created by jqGrid internally. You can't add class to elements which are not exist and `loadComplete` is one from the first callbacks which will be called after the chechboxes are placed on the page.

Comment: am calling one function on button click which converts all the checkbox into imaged checkbox and only on tat button click i need to enable my multiselect columns. is there any existing example you can loop to on this scenario with jqgrid?

Comment: @Peru: Like I wrote in my answer one can't just "convert" `<input>` element to `<img>`. Moreover you should understand that such conversion can break parts of existing jqGrid code which uses sometimes selectors like `"input.cbox"`. You have to post more exact code which you use to get an answer. An example from [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17186822/315935) I could wrote only after analysing the code of `prettyCheckable` plugin.

Comment: Thanks @Oleg. Am trying something here. Ll post and get back with clear informations. Thanks for your time :)